# Fallback plan when maven repository (i.e. jCenter, mavenCenter) goes down?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, devops, maven-central

Most Android projects use external dependencies (library). Those libraries can be added as jar or as gradle dependency. Adding as a gradle dependency is easier to add, manage and update. Those dependencies are often hosted on repositories like jCenter or MavenCentral.

This can be a dangerous dependencies on those repositories. When any of such host repository goes down, projects stop building (with clean build). For example, jCenter is down (which was available in read-only mode after sunset) and I feel stuck as a transient's transient dependency is served only from jCenter and I dont have control over it. This is a significant impact on developer's and team's efficiency.

How do big corp like Airbnb, Uber make sure their team is not stuck in such situation?

Theoretically, a private repo that fetches and caches required versions from actual servers can come to rescue when it goes down. Is there any such solution that not so big companies can use?

Comment: You should have an internal proxy/mirror which your build systems use

Answer (score 0):

According to my simple experience, BigTech uses artifactory, Either by atlassian cloud or locally installed by buying the product.

You can use [mavenLocal](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html) in a small office to store the artifactory and versions like you are using jcenter or MavenCentral.

This is gradle friendly with easy set up ad easy upload and can be integrated easily with already done projects.